# How to use AngularJS broadcast between different states?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcast

I have function `editPrcChallenge` where i am routing user to child state and broadcasting `challengekey`, Broadcast is invoking but its not going inside the function, Any idea what i have implemented wrong ?

So far tried code....

parent.js

```
$scope.editPrcChallenge = function (challengeKey) {
    $scope.$broadcast('editPrcChallenge',challengeKey);
    $state.go('app.editChallenge',{processId:$stateParams.processId,challengeKey:challengeKey});
};
```

child.js

```
$scope.$on('editPrcChallenge', function (s,challengeKey){
    console.log(challengeKey);
    $scope.editMode = true;
    // $scope.clearFields = clearForm();
    processFactory.getProcessChallengeInfo(challengeKey)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.challengesDTO =response.data;
            $scope.showEscalation = !!$scope.challengesDTO.challengeDesLkupCode;
        });
};
```

Comment: Is state 'app.editChallenge' the child state? And if so, are you trying to broadcast an event from the parent view and THEN navigate to the child view, who you expect should process the broadcasted event?

Comment: You're immediately transitioning states after broadcasting the event. If the child was in the DOM, I think its $scope is destroyed before the event listener is fired. If the child is coming into the dom because of the state change, your probably may be that child isn't in the DOM yet. Changing states right after that broadcast is a bit hard to reason about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking into my issue i got it resolved and updated my question , basically i needed to add challengeKey as $stateParams now broadcast is working and getting the challengeKey in child $scope.

```
$scope.editPrcChallenge = function (challengeKey) {
       $scope.$broadcast('editPrcChallenge',challengeKey);
       $state.go('app.editChallenge',{processId:$stateParams.processId,challengeKey:challengeKey});
    };


 if($stateParams.challengeKey) {
        console.log($stateParams.challengeKey);
             $scope.editMode = true;
            // $scope.clearFields = clearForm();
             processFactory.getProcessChallengeInfo($stateParams.challengeKey).then(function(response){
                  $scope.challengesDTO =response.data;
                  $scope.showEscalation = !!$scope.challengesDTO.challengeDesLkupCode;
                });
```